# How do I filter a dataframe according to a list of pattern

Tags: r, filter

I need to filter this table (`head` shown below) on RStudio:

```
gene_callers_id source   accession                 function.  e_value             
<int> <chr>    <chr>                     <chr>        <dbl> 1         
4439568 MGE_type 2545_tnpA_CR555306.1      tnpA      3.11e-28 2         
4439574 MGE_type 1420_IS91_CP003742.1      IS91      2   e-14 3         
4439922 MGE_type 1112_qacEdelta_AF261825.2 qacEdelta 3.48e-12 4         
4440357 MGE_type 1610_int3_HE616890.1      int3      1.77e-26 5         
4440603 MGE_type 1151_IS621_NC009800       IS621     7.18e-39 6         
4440805 MGE_type 1010_tnpA_AJ233397.3      tnpA      8.71e-73
```

According to this list of accession number:

```
`V1 
1 IPR000802 
2 IPR001802 
3 IPR002657 
4 IPR003370 
5 IPR003457 
6 IPR003691`
```

tried using this code but didn’t work:

```
mrg_accession <- as.vector(read.csv("mrg_accession.csv", header = FALSE, colClasses = "character"))
mrg_dbs <- filter(func_all, grepl(mrg_accession, accession, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Comment: I guess you need `unlist` instead of `as.vector` and then use `filter(func_all, grepl(paste(mrg_accession, collapse = "|"), accesssion, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Comment: thanks!! apparently if grepl is used, only the first element will be used. any idea what I should use instead?

Comment: Have you tried the `paste` in my comment `filter(func_all, grepl(paste(mrg_accession, collapse = "|"), accesssion, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

We may just extract the column `V1` by using either `$` or `[[` or even `unlist` (as there is only a single column) and not `as.vector`.  Then `paste` the column values to a single character delimited by `|` for the `pattern` in `grepl`

```
mrg_accession <-read.csv("mrg_accession.csv", header = FALSE, 
colClasses = "character")$V1
library(dplyr)
filter(func_all, grepl(paste(mrg_accession, collapse = "|"), 
      accession, ignore.case = TRUE))
```